# Strip html tags before callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I use `AjaxHelper.BeginForm` to create ajax form in my view. The view has a `textarea` to provide content. How can I remove html tags from this textarea before form is submited. What I mean:

- user clicks 'button'
- tags are stripped
- callback is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string, but note that it is not 100% reliable.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var text = $("#someElement").val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

    // make callback with above variable...
});
```

Comment: ok, but after replacing text, will the callback be made automatically?

Comment: No, you would need to do that yourself in whatever manner your `AjaxHelper.BeginForm` requires.

Comment: are you using ajax to submit the form?